# Sharepoint 2013 master page footer not work

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

i edit in my master page in SharePoint 2013 files like that

```
<%-- SPG:

This HTML file has been associated with a SharePoint Master Page (.master file) carrying the same name.  While the files remain associated, you will not be allowed to edit the .master file, and any rename, move, or deletion operations will be reciprocated.

To build the master page directly from this HTML file, simply edit the page as you normally would.  Use the Snippet Generator at http://ali.websp.local/_layouts/15/ComponentHome.aspx?Url=http%3A%2F%2Fali%2Ewebsp%2Elocal%2F%5Fcatalogs%2Fmasterpage%2FDusty%2Findex%2Emaster to create and customize useful SharePoint entities, then copy and paste them as HTML snippets into your HTML code.   All updates to this file will automatically sync to the associated Master Page.

 --%>
<%@Master language="C#"%>
<%@Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>
<%@Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>
<%@Register TagPrefix="wssucw" TagName="Welcome" Src="~/_controltemplates/15/Welcome.ascx"%>
<%@Register TagPrefix="wssucmui" TagName="MUISelector" Src="~/_controltemplates/15/MUISelector.ascx"%>
<%@Register TagPrefix="PublishingRibbon" TagName="PublishingRibbon" Src="~/_controltemplates/15/Ribbon.ascx"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<SharePoint:SPHtmlTag runat="server" id="SPHtmlTag" dir="&lt;%$Resources:wss,multipages_direction_dir_value%&gt;">
    <head runat="server">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />




        <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
        <SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag runat="server">
        </SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag>
        <SharePoint:PageTitle runat="server">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
                <SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server">
                </SharePoint:ProjectProperty>
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </SharePoint:PageTitle>
        <SharePoint:StartScript runat="server">
        </SharePoint:StartScript>
        <SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" Version="15">
        </SharePoint:CssLink>
        <SharePoint:CacheManifestLink runat="server">
        </SharePoint:CacheManifestLink>
        <SharePoint:PageRenderMode runat="server" RenderModeType="Standard">
        </SharePoint:PageRenderMode>
        <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="core.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false">
        </SharePoint:ScriptLink>
        <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="menu.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false">
        </SharePoint:ScriptLink>
        <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="callout.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false">
        </SharePoint:ScriptLink>
        <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="sharing.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false">
        </SharePoint:ScriptLink>
        <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="suitelinks.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false">
        </SharePoint:ScriptLink>
        <SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server">
        </SharePoint:CustomJSUrl>
        <SharePoint:SoapDiscoveryLink runat="server">
        </SharePoint:SoapDiscoveryLink>
        <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" Container="false" runat="server">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="AdditionalPageHead" AllowMultipleControls="true">
            </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
        <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="Themable/corev15.css" runat="server">
        </SharePoint:CssRegistration>
        <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaSPWebPartManager" runat="server">
            <WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager runat="server">
            </WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager>
        </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <SharePoint:CssRegistration name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Dusty/styles.css %&gt;" runat="server" after="SharepointCssFile"/>
        <link rel="icon" href="/_catalogs/masterpage/Dusty/images/icon.ico" />

    </head>
    <body onhashchange="if (typeof(_spBodyOnHashChange) != 'undefined') _spBodyOnHashChange();">
    <SharePoint:SPClientIDGenerator runat="server" ServerControlID="DeltaPlaceHolderMain;DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea;DeltaPlaceHolderUtilityContent"/>
    <SharePoint:ImageLink runat="server"/><SharePoint:SharePointForm onsubmit="if (typeof(_spFormOnSubmitWrapper) != 'undefined') {return _spFormOnSubmitWrapper();} else {return true;}" runat="server" __designer:Preview="&lt;table cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0 style=&quot;font:messagebox;color:buttontext;background-color:buttonface;border: solid 1px;border-top-color:buttonhighlight;border-left-color:buttonhighlight;border-bottom-color:buttonshadow;border-right-color:buttonshadow&quot;&gt;
              &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td nowrap&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-weight:bold&quot;&gt;SharePointForm&lt;/span&gt; - Unnamed4&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
              &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
            &lt;/table&gt;" __designer:Values="&lt;P N=&#39;Method&#39; T=&#39;post&#39; /&gt;&lt;P N=&#39;Name&#39; ID=&#39;1&#39; T=&#39;aspnetForm&#39; /&gt;&lt;P N=&#39;TagName&#39; T=&#39;form&#39; /&gt;&lt;P N=&#39;ID&#39; T=&#39;ctl03&#39; /&gt;&lt;P N=&#39;Page&#39; ID=&#39;2&#39; /&gt;&lt;P N=&#39;TemplateControl&#39; ID=&#39;3&#39; /&gt;&lt;P N=&#39;AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory&#39; R=&#39;-1&#39; /&gt;"><asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="false" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="false" EnableScriptLocalization="true" />



        <SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" HideFromSearchCrawler="true" EmitDiv="true">
            <div id="TurnOnAccessibility" style="display:none" class="s4-notdlg noindex">
                <a id="linkTurnOnAcc" href="#" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" onclick="SetIsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled(true);UpdateAccessibilityUI();document.getElementById('linkTurnOffAcc').focus();return false;">
                    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="&lt;%$Resources:wss,master_turnonaccessibility%&gt;" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode">
                    </SharePoint:EncodedLiteral>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="TurnOffAccessibility" style="display:none" class="s4-notdlg noindex">
                <a id="linkTurnOffAcc" href="#" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" onclick="SetIsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled(false);UpdateAccessibilityUI();document.getElementById('linkTurnOnAcc').focus();return false;">
                    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="&lt;%$Resources:wss,master_turnoffaccessibility%&gt;" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode">
                    </SharePoint:EncodedLiteral>
                </a>
            </div>
        </SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
        <div id="ms-designer-ribbon">
            <PublishingRibbon:PublishingRibbon runat="server" />

        </div>
        <SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" AuthenticationRestrictions="AnonymousUsersOnly">
            <wssucw:Welcome runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
            </wssucw:Welcome>
        </SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>

        <div id="s4-workspace">
            <div id="s4-bodyContainer">
                <div id="headWrap">
                    <div id="headpanel">
                        <div id="logo">
                            <h1>dusky
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div id="quots">Neque porro quisquam est qui , consectetur, adipisci velit..."
                        </div>
                        <div id="menu">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Home
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="gap">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">About Us
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="gap">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Newsletter
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="gap">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Duty
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="gap">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Output
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="gap">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Solution
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="gap">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Testimonial
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="gap">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Contact Us
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div data-name="ContentPlaceHolderMain">


                    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta ID="DeltaPlaceHolderMain" IsMainContent="true" runat="server">
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
                            <div class="DefaultContentBlock" style="border:medium black solid; background:yellow; color:black; margin:20px; padding:10px;">
             <div id="contentWrap">
                    <div id="contentPanel">
                        <div id="leftPanel">
                            <div class="toplinks">

                            </div>
                            <div id="loginPanel">

                            </div>
                            <div id="projectsPanel">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="middlePanel">
                            <div class="top">

                            </div>
                            <div class="bottom">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="rigtPanel">
                            <div class="services">

                            </div>
                            <div class="contacts">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                            </div>
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaFormDigest" BlockElement="true" runat="server"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderFormDigest" runat="server"><SharePoint:formdigest runat="server" /></asp:ContentPlaceHolder></SharePoint:AjaxDelta></SharePoint:SharePointForm><SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderUtilityContent" runat="server"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderUtilityContent" runat="server" /></SharePoint:AjaxDelta><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleAreaClass" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigationSiteMap" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigation" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderHorizontalNav" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarDataSource" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderCalendarNavigator" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftActions" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarTop" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSiteName" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageDescription" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageImage" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleLeftBorder" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMiniConsole" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleRightMargin" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleAreaSeparator" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderNavSpacer" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarBorder" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyLeftBorder" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyRightMargin" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="WSSDesignConsole" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="SPNavigation" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchTop" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottom" Visible="False" runat="server" /></body>
</SharePoint:SPHtmlTag>
    <div id="footWrap">
                    <div id="footPanel">
                        <div id="footNav">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Home
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="blank">|
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">About Us
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="blank">|
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Newsletter
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="blank">|
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Duty
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="blank">|
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Output
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="blank">|
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Solution
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="blank">|
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Testimonial
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="blank">|
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Contact Us
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <p>© Copyright Information Goes Here. All Rights Reserved.
                        </p>
                        <p>Designed by 
                            <a href="http://www.templateworld.com/">TemplateWorld
                            </a>
 and brought to you by                             <a href="http://www.smashingmagazine.com/">SmashingMagazine
                            </a>
                        </p>
                        <div id="validation">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer">xhtml
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="blank">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">css
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

but the footer not work i don't know why i think its problem in content place holder i try to change footer code inside the content place holder but its give me same result
can any one help me please?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is it invisible, not looking as you want or something else?

Comment: i inspect element and the footer is not there the browser not read its HTML i try that i IE and chrome same

Comment: i was not able to edit in the master page so i create new one in same folder and edit my code is that could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

sorry its work now the problem was that the footer was out of the main div here how i fix it

```
<%-- SPG:

This HTML file has been associated with a SharePoint Master Page (.master file) carrying the same name.  While the files remain associated, you will not be allowed to edit the .master file, and any rename, move, or deletion operations will be reciprocated.

To build the master page directly from this HTML file, simply edit the page as you normally would.  Use the Snippet Generator at http://ali.websp.local/_layouts/15/ComponentHome.aspx?Url=http%3A%2F%2Fali%2Ewebsp%2Elocal%2F%5Fcatalogs%2Fmasterpage%2FDusty%2Findex%2Emaster to create and customize useful SharePoint entities, then copy and paste them as HTML snippets into your HTML code.   All updates to this file will automatically sync to the associated Master Page.

 --%>
<%@Master language="C#"%>
<%@Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>
<%@Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>
<%@Register TagPrefix="wssucw" TagName="Welcome" Src="~/_controltemplates/15/Welcome.ascx"%>
<%@Register TagPrefix="wssucmui" TagName="MUISelector" Src="~/_controltemplates/15/MUISelector.ascx"%>
<%@Register TagPrefix="PublishingRibbon" TagName="PublishingRibbon" Src="~/_controltemplates/15/Ribbon.ascx"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<SharePoint:SPHtmlTag runat="server" id="SPHtmlTag" dir="&lt;%$Resources:wss,multipages_direction_dir_value%&gt;">
    <head runat="server">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />




        <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
        <SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag runat="server">
        </SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag>
        <SharePoint:PageTitle runat="server">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
                <SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server">
                </SharePoint:ProjectProperty>
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </SharePoint:PageTitle>
        <SharePoint:StartScript runat="server">
        </SharePoint:StartScript>
        <SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" Version="15">
        </SharePoint:CssLink>
        <SharePoint:CacheManifestLink runat="server">
        </SharePoint:CacheManifestLink>
        <SharePoint:PageRenderMode runat="server" RenderModeType="Standard">
        </SharePoint:PageRenderMode>
        <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="core.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false">
        </SharePoint:ScriptLink>
        <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="menu.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false">
        </SharePoint:ScriptLink>
        <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="callout.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false">
        </SharePoint:ScriptLink>
        <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="sharing.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false">
        </SharePoint:ScriptLink>
        <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="suitelinks.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false">
        </SharePoint:ScriptLink>
        <SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server">
        </SharePoint:CustomJSUrl>
        <SharePoint:SoapDiscoveryLink runat="server">
        </SharePoint:SoapDiscoveryLink>
        <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" Container="false" runat="server">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="AdditionalPageHead" AllowMultipleControls="true">
            </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
        <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="Themable/corev15.css" runat="server">
        </SharePoint:CssRegistration>
        <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaSPWebPartManager" runat="server">
            <WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager runat="server">
            </WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager>
        </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <SharePoint:CssRegistration name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Dusty/styles.css %&gt;" runat="server" after="SharepointCssFile"/>
        <link rel="icon" href="/_catalogs/masterpage/Dusty/images/icon.ico" />

    </head>
    <body onhashchange="if (typeof(_spBodyOnHashChange) != 'undefined') _spBodyOnHashChange();">
    <SharePoint:SPClientIDGenerator runat="server" ServerControlID="DeltaPlaceHolderMain;DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea;DeltaPlaceHolderUtilityContent"/>
    <SharePoint:ImageLink runat="server"/><SharePoint:SharePointForm onsubmit="if (typeof(_spFormOnSubmitWrapper) != 'undefined') {return _spFormOnSubmitWrapper();} else {return true;}" runat="server" __designer:Preview="&lt;table cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0 style=&quot;font:messagebox;color:buttontext;background-color:buttonface;border: solid 1px;border-top-color:buttonhighlight;border-left-color:buttonhighlight;border-bottom-color:buttonshadow;border-right-color:buttonshadow&quot;&gt;
              &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td nowrap&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-weight:bold&quot;&gt;SharePointForm&lt;/span&gt; - Unnamed4&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
              &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
            &lt;/table&gt;" __designer:Values="&lt;P N=&#39;Method&#39; T=&#39;post&#39; /&gt;&lt;P N=&#39;Name&#39; ID=&#39;1&#39; T=&#39;aspnetForm&#39; /&gt;&lt;P N=&#39;TagName&#39; T=&#39;form&#39; /&gt;&lt;P N=&#39;ID&#39; T=&#39;ctl03&#39; /&gt;&lt;P N=&#39;Page&#39; ID=&#39;2&#39; /&gt;&lt;P N=&#39;TemplateControl&#39; ID=&#39;3&#39; /&gt;&lt;P N=&#39;AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory&#39; R=&#39;-1&#39; /&gt;"><asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="false" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="false" EnableScriptLocalization="true" />



        <SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" HideFromSearchCrawler="true" EmitDiv="true">
            <div id="TurnOnAccessibility" style="display:none" class="s4-notdlg noindex">
                <a id="linkTurnOnAcc" href="#" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" onclick="SetIsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled(true);UpdateAccessibilityUI();document.getElementById('linkTurnOffAcc').focus();return false;">
                    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="&lt;%$Resources:wss,master_turnonaccessibility%&gt;" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode">
                    </SharePoint:EncodedLiteral>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="TurnOffAccessibility" style="display:none" class="s4-notdlg noindex">
                <a id="linkTurnOffAcc" href="#" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" onclick="SetIsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled(false);UpdateAccessibilityUI();document.getElementById('linkTurnOnAcc').focus();return false;">
                    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="&lt;%$Resources:wss,master_turnoffaccessibility%&gt;" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode">
                    </SharePoint:EncodedLiteral>
                </a>
            </div>
        </SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
        <div id="ms-designer-ribbon">
            <PublishingRibbon:PublishingRibbon runat="server" />

        </div>
        <SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" AuthenticationRestrictions="AnonymousUsersOnly">
            <wssucw:Welcome runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
            </wssucw:Welcome>
        </SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>

        <div id="s4-workspace">
            <div id="s4-bodyContainer">
                <div id="headWrap">
                    <div id="headpanel">
                        <div id="logo">
                            <h1>dusky
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div id="quots">Neque porro quisquam est qui , consectetur, adipisci velit..."
                        </div>
                        <div id="menu">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Home
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="gap">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">About Us
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="gap">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Newsletter
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="gap">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Duty
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="gap">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Output
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="gap">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Solution
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="gap">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Testimonial
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="gap">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Contact Us
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div data-name="ContentPlaceHolderMain">


                    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta ID="DeltaPlaceHolderMain" IsMainContent="true" runat="server">
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
                            <div class="DefaultContentBlock" style="border:medium black solid; background:yellow; color:black; margin:20px; padding:10px;">
             <div id="contentWrap">
                    <div id="contentPanel">
                        <div id="leftPanel">
                            <div class="toplinks">

                            </div>
                            <div id="loginPanel">

                            </div>
                            <div id="projectsPanel">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="middlePanel">
                            <div class="top">

                            </div>
                            <div class="bottom">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="rigtPanel">
                            <div class="services">

                            </div>
                            <div class="contacts">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                            </div>
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footWrap">
                    <div id="footPanel">
                        <div id="footNav">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Home
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="blank">|
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">About Us
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="blank">|
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Newsletter
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="blank">|
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Duty
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="blank">|
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Output
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="blank">|
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Solution
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="blank">|
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Testimonial
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="blank">|
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Contact Us
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <p>© Copyright Information Goes Here. All Rights Reserved.
                        </p>
                        <p>Designed by 
                            <a href="http://www.templateworld.com/">TemplateWorld
                            </a>
 and brought to you by                             <a href="http://www.smashingmagazine.com/">SmashingMagazine
                            </a>
                        </p>
                        <div id="validation">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer">xhtml
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="blank">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">css
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>

    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaFormDigest" BlockElement="true" runat="server"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderFormDigest" runat="server"><SharePoint:formdigest runat="server" /></asp:ContentPlaceHolder></SharePoint:AjaxDelta></SharePoint:SharePointForm><SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderUtilityContent" runat="server"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderUtilityContent" runat="server" /></SharePoint:AjaxDelta><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleAreaClass" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigationSiteMap" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigation" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderHorizontalNav" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarDataSource" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderCalendarNavigator" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftActions" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarTop" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSiteName" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageDescription" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageImage" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleLeftBorder" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMiniConsole" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleRightMargin" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleAreaSeparator" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderNavSpacer" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarBorder" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyLeftBorder" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyRightMargin" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="WSSDesignConsole" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="SPNavigation" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchTop" Visible="False" runat="server" /><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottom" Visible="False" runat="server" /></body>
</SharePoint:SPHtmlTag>
```